# Does high pin impedance affect the need for resistors?

Tags: motor-controller, input-impedance

I'm designing a brushless motor controller as a hobby project. I'm using the MP6538 gate driver (datasheet here: [1](https://www.monolithicpower.com/en/documentview/productdocument/index/version/2/document_type/Datasheet/lang/en/sku/MP6538/document_id/3917/)), and I have some questions about pin impedance and whether or not resistors are necessary.

I'm routing pins 22 and 24 (nBRAKE and DIR) to a header with the intention to use buttons to switch braking and direction states. The datasheet says that the maximum logic input current is 14 microamps, so I've used 330k ohm resistors. Is this necessary? Or can I assume that the input impedance is high enough that I don't need resistors?

Similarly, pin 27 (OCREF) is a feature that measures the voltage on the OCREF pin to the voltage drop across each MOSFET due to its RDS(on) to prevent overcurrent. I've used a resistor divider here to set the voltage on the OCREF pin, but are the resistor values too high or low?

[image]

Comment: If your intent is to force those signals high or low, I would suggest using a 10K pullup to 5V on each signal.  Connect the button to the signal, and to GND.  You may want to add a small capacitor from each signal to GND, and a 1K resistor to the button to provide a rudimentary switch de-bounce circuit.

Comment: Thanks, I'll make sure to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 14 uA current listed in the datasheet is the maximum current the logic input will draw at the specified voltage level. The input logic ensures that only this much current will be drawn. You do not need to add current limiting resistors to the inputs.

Comment: Thanks for the response. How would I approach selecting resistor values for R2 and R3 if I don't know the impedance of the OCREF pin?

Comment: OCREF is input to OPAMP, which has high input impedance, ideally no current will be drawn by the OPAMP . selected values should be ok ..